# Integrating wordpress with my site

Tags: php, wordpress

I've my site at http://www.domain.com/site and my wordpress blog at http://www.domain.com/blog.

While trying to integrate the wordpress with the site, I've included

```
// Include WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

It shows a error 500 when accessed on the browser. How do I give the path to the wp-blog-header??
NOTE: open_basedir restriction is also there in my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best idea is, to recreate the blog layout for your site. It will take some time and you'll need some basic html + css skills, but it's the best option

Comment: what do you mean by "recreating a blog layout??" What I actually want is to display the latest 2-3 posts from the blog at the index page at domain.com/site

Comment: Then just connect from your site to the wordpress-database and fetch the last three rows?

Comment: @ptamzz Simplest way I've found to do that is to plug in one of the many options for displaying posts from an RSS feed, then just point it at your blog's RSS feed. You can do it server-side, rolling your own with a simple RSS reader like Magpie, or there's lots of client-side options to grab a feed and show it with Javascript. No need to do anything smart with WordPress if you don't have to, and if you change the blog engine, you just point it at the new feed and it carries on working.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path of the header file correct? Try giving it an absolute path.

This article has integration details, and the only thing you could get wrong is the path. Do you have any custom .htaccess instructions?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website